# How can I parse and get values from this INI file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

My INI (`config.ini`) file looks like below

```
#this is comment
[Folder]
C:\temp
C:\dir1
C:\dir2
```

How can I get the content of `[Folder]` using powershell?

I need the folder path in an array

The example I've seen are with name value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example config.ini:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$a = GC .\CONFIG.INI
[string[]]$b=$a.GetRange( $a.IndexOf("[Folder]")+1, ( $a.Count - ($a.IndexOf("[Folder]")+1)))
$b
C:\temp
C:\dir1
C:\dir2
```

Comment: Thanks works, but if I add one more `[xxxxx]`  in the ini file it fails. For now i only neeed one. hence accepting this answser. thanks for your time

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan glad to help. In case there's more [xxxx] fix the range with `($a.IndexOf("[Folder]")+1, ( $a.IndexOf("[xxxx]") - $a.indexof("[Folder]")))`