# How do I get INI section file with Powershell by executing script in Command-Line?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have PowerShell script to get the value of section in `INI file`. I can get the value by executing it in PowerShell itself, but I want to `remove the section name in PowerShell Script`, I want to use the name of the section of INI file in `Command-Line` through I execute the script.

I tried this command from command line with this code :

```
powershell.ps1 -FilePath C:\User\test.ini .
```

It return `1200unit` #But this is not my expectation#

My INI file:

```
[Information]
Computer=1200unit
TV=100unit
AC=20unit

[Feature]
Basic=120
Medium=30
Advance=40
```

Here the code that I tried to get the value through PowerShell itself.

```
# Global script parameters.
Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath, $ini
)

# Definition of the function to get the file
Function Get-IniFile
{
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
        $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
        $ini_file[$section] = @{}
    } else {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
    }
    }
        $Get = $ini_file.Information.Computer #Expectation to remove this#
        $Get
}

# Calling the function with the global parameter $FilePath
Get-IniFile $FilePath
```

If I remove this part from script :

```
$Get = $ini_file.Information.Computer #Expectation to remove this#
$Get
```

I tried this command to get the value :

```
powershell.ps1 -FilePath C:\User\test.ini $ini_file.(Information.Computer)
```

It return an error :

```
The term 'Information.Computer' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

My expectation result is, I can use command line to get the value of each section INI file.
For the example : `powershell.ps1 -FilePath C:\User\test.ini Information.Computer`
It will return `1200unit`

Comment: two ideas ... [1] add a `-Section` and a `-Setting` parameter to parse the parts you want.. [2] parse the whole thing, pass the whole thing out, and take the parts you want AFTER you get the whole thing back. ///// the 2nd is likely both easier and more useful. [*grin*]

Comment: [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)

Comment: the way to get the parts that I need is my problem @Lee_Dailey

Comment: I tried this, store the whole data of INI file in variable` $Get`
But I don't know how to get the value of each section from command-line.
`$Get = Get-Content $FilePath
$Get`

Comment: @Job - it looks like `postanote` has posted a variant that parses the ENTIRE ini file and then sends that out as an object that you can address the properties [headings] & sub-properties [settings] with `$Result.HeadingName.SettingName`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of these two ...

[PowerShell to Read single value from simple .ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690336/powershell-to-read-single-value-from-simple-ini-file)

```
function Get-IniFile 
{  
    param(  
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $filePath  
    )  

    $anonymous = "NoSection"

    $ini = @{}  
    switch -regex -file $filePath  
    {  
        "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section  
        {  
            $section = $matches[1]  
            $ini[$section] = @{}  
            $CommentCount = 0  
        }  

        "^(;.*)$" # Comment  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = $anonymous  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $value = $matches[1]  
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1  
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value  
        }   

        "(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" # Key  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = $anonymous  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value  
        }  
    }  

    return $ini  
}  

$iniFile = Get-IniFile .\ADAP.ini
$app = $iniFile.NoSection.APP
$dll = $iniFile.NoSection.DLL
```

[How can I parse and get values from this INI file using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355389/how-can-i-parse-and-get-values-from-this-ini-file-using-powershell)

Try these three implementations for your use case...

Use PowerShell to Work with Any INI File

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ea40c1ef-c856-434b-b8fb-ebd7a76e8d91

[beruic/ini.ps1](https://gist.github.com/beruic/1be71ae570646bca40734280ea357e3c)

[How to Parse an INI file in Powershell](https://www.dev4sys.com/2016/05/how-to-parse-ini-file-in-powershell.html)

```
function parseIniFile
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [String] $Inputfile
    )

if ($Inputfile -eq "")
{
    Write-Error "Ini File Parser: No file specified or selected to parse."
    Break
}
else
{

    $ContentFile = Get-Content $Inputfile
    # commented Section
    $COMMENT_CHARACTERS = ";"
    # match section header
    $HEADER_REGEX = "\[+[A-Z0-9._ %<>/#+-]+\]" 

        $OccurenceOfComment = 0
        $ContentComment   = $ContentFile | Where { ($_ -match "^\s*$COMMENT_CHARACTERS") -or ($_ -match "^$COMMENT_CHARACTERS")  }  | % { 
            [PSCustomObject]@{ Comment= $_ ; 
                 Index = [Array]::IndexOf($ContentFile,$_) 
            }
            $OccurenceOfComment++
        }

        $COMMENT_INI = @()
        foreach ($COMMENT_ELEMENT in $ContentComment){
            $COMMENT_OBJ = New-Object PSObject
            $COMMENT_OBJ | Add-Member  -type NoteProperty -name Index -value $COMMENT_ELEMENT.Index
            $COMMENT_OBJ | Add-Member  -type NoteProperty -name Comment -value $COMMENT_ELEMENT.Comment
            $COMMENT_INI += $COMMENT_OBJ
        }

        $CONTENT_USEFUL = $ContentFile | Where { ($_ -notmatch "^\s*$COMMENT_CHARACTERS") -or ($_ -notmatch "^$COMMENT_CHARACTERS") } 
        $ALL_SECTION_HASHTABLE      = $CONTENT_USEFUL | Where { $_ -match $HEADER_REGEX  } | % { [PSCustomObject]@{ Section= $_ ; Index = [Array]::IndexOf($CONTENT_USEFUL,$_) }}
        #$ContentUncomment | Select-String -AllMatches $HEADER_REGEX | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches

        $SECTION_INI = @()
        foreach ($SECTION_ELEMENT in $ALL_SECTION_HASHTABLE){
            $SECTION_OBJ = New-Object PSObject
            $SECTION_OBJ | Add-Member  -type NoteProperty -name Index -value $SECTION_ELEMENT.Index
            $SECTION_OBJ | Add-Member  -type NoteProperty -name Section -value $SECTION_ELEMENT.Section
            $SECTION_INI += $SECTION_OBJ
        }

        $INI_FILE_CONTENT = @()
        $NBR_OF_SECTION = $SECTION_INI.count
        $NBR_MAX_LINE   = $CONTENT_USEFUL.count

        #*********************************************
        # select each lines and value of each section 
        #*********************************************
        for ($i=1; $i -le $NBR_OF_SECTION ; $i++){
            if($i -ne $NBR_OF_SECTION){
                if(($SECTION_INI[$i-1].Index+1) -eq ($SECTION_INI[$i].Index )){        
                    $CONVERTED_OBJ = @() #There is nothing between the two section
                } 
                else{
                    $SECTION_STRING = $CONTENT_USEFUL | Select-Object -Index  (($SECTION_INI[$i-1].Index+1)..($SECTION_INI[$i].Index-1)) | Out-String
                    $CONVERTED_OBJ = convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $SECTION_STRING
                }
            }
            else{
                if(($SECTION_INI[$i-1].Index+1) -eq $NBR_MAX_LINE){        
                    $CONVERTED_OBJ = @() #There is nothing between the two section
                } 
                else{
                    $SECTION_STRING = $CONTENT_USEFUL | Select-Object -Index  (($SECTION_INI[$i-1].Index+1)..($NBR_MAX_LINE-1)) | Out-String
                    $CONVERTED_OBJ = convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $SECTION_STRING
                }
            }
            $CURRENT_SECTION = New-Object PSObject
            $CURRENT_SECTION | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Section -Value $SECTION_INI[$i-1].Section
            $CURRENT_SECTION | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Content -Value $CONVERTED_OBJ
            $INI_FILE_CONTENT += $CURRENT_SECTION
        }
     return $INI_FILE_CONTENT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I used this script.

```
# Global script parameters.
Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath, $ini, $a, $b
)

# Definition of the function to get the file
Function Get-IniFile
{
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
        $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
        $ini_file[$section] = @{}
    } else {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
    }
    }

     $Get = $ini_file.($a).($b)
     $Get
}



# Calling the function with the global parameter $FilePath
Get-IniFile $FilePath
```

In command line I used this command to get the value :
powershell.ps1 -FilePath `C:\User\test.ini -a Information -b Computer`
It return `1200unit`

Thanks all for the advice.